# Why PHP have so weird function parameter positioning?

Tags: php

PHP is easy language to learn but one thing that's triggering me is PHP's positions of function parameters.

**Example #1**

```
array_walk($array, $callback);
array_map($callback, $array);
```

**Example #2**

```
array_push($array, $mixed);
array_search($mixed, $array);
```

It just don't make any sense. Does PHP developers make this intentionally?

Comment: "_Does PHP developers make this intentionally_" Yes they do. (You should really ask this the PHP developers, what kind of answer are you expecting here?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all to do with what they do with an array. `array_walk` modifies the array by reference whilst `array_map` returns a new array.

Again, `array_push` modifies the array by reference and `array_search` returns a value from the array.

Where the array comes first in the arguments; will tend to mean the array will be modified by the function. It's very useful as a developer to know which functions are likely to modify the array being passed in.

Example:

```
<?php

$myArray = [1,2,3];
array_push($myArray,4);
var_dump($myArray); // array(1,2,3,4);

$myArray = [1,2,3]; 
$result = array_map(function ($val) { return $val * 2; }, $myArray);
var_dump($myArray); // array(1,2,3);
var_dump($result); // array(2,4,6);
```

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense to me.

Comment: `arrray_map` can also take multiple arrays as parameters so they must be last ones.